# how to "reverse" the output bash

Tags: bash, sorting, cut, uniq

I have an output that looks like this: (number of occurrences of the word, and the word)

```
    3 I
    2 come
    2 from
    1 Slovenia
```

But I want that it looked like this:

```
I 3
come 2
from 2
Slovenia 1
```

I got my output with:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 "file" | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

I tried to do different things, with another pipes:

```
 cut -d' ' -f1 "file" | uniq -c | sort -nr | cut -d' ' -f8 ...?
```

which is a good start, because I have the words on the first place..buuut I have no access to the number of occurrences?

AWK and SED are not allowed!

EDIT:
alright lets say the file looks like this.

```
I ....
come ...
from ... 
Slovenia ...
I ...
I ....
come ...
from ....
```

I is repeated 3 times, come twice, from twice, Slovenia once. +They are on beginning of each line.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `awk` or `sed`? Seems like an arbitrary prohibition.

Comment: It's stupid, I know. I did my whole homework with awk, and then i read that it is not allowed. But yeah, this thing is my homework and professors decided not to allow awk.

Comment: perl ;-) `echo "    1 Slovenia" | perl -nE 's/ *([0-9]*) *(.*)/$2 $1/; print'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AWK and SED are not allowed!

Starting with this:

```
$ cat file
    3 I
    2 come
    2 from
    1 Slovenia
```

The order can be reversed with this:

```
$ while read count word; do echo "$word $count"; done <file
I 3
come 2
from 2
Slovenia 1
```

#### Complete pipeline

Let us start with:

```
$ cat file2
I ....
come ...
from ... 
Slovenia ...
I ...
I ....
come ...
from ....
```

Using your pipeline (with two changes) combined with the `while` loop:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f1 "file2" | sort | uniq -c | sort -snr | while read count word; do echo "$word $count"; done 
I 3
come 2
from 2
Slovenia 1
```

The one change that I made to the pipeline was to put a `sort` before `uniq -c`.   This is because `uniq -c` assumes that its input is sorted.  The second change is to add the `-s` option to the second sort so that the alphabetical order of the words with the same count is not lost

Comment: Yeah but my file does not look like this. I have to count the occurrences of the file and then reverse them

Comment: @RokDolinar OK, I was working with what was shown in the question.  What does your file does look like?

Comment: Okay i gave bad example but id doesn't matter. The file has those for words. "I" is repeated "3" times, come " times, from 2 times, and Slovenia once. + they are the first word in a each line

Comment: @RokDolinar, it would probably help if you showed what your source file looks like.

Comment: I edited my main post. You should also look at my code which i did so far and what it does.

Comment: @John1024's answer works if you pipe it into your previous output (with a minor improvement. I'll edit the answer to work without saving the output to a file first

Comment: @redbmk  Yes, thanks.  (Please don't edit without checking for my latest change.)

Comment: @John1024, yeah you beat me to it. The extra `sort` is the change I was going to make as well.

Comment: @RokDolinar I just updated the answer to explicitly include your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pipe an `awk` after your first try:

```
$ cat so.txt
    3 I
    2 come
    2 from
    1 Slovenia

$ cat so.txt | awk '{ print $2 " " $1}'
I 3
come 2
from 2
Slovenia 1
```

Comment: awk is not allowed in my case :/

Answer (score 0):

If perl is allowed:

```
$ cat testfile
I ....
come ...
from ... 
Slovenia ...
I ...
I ....
come ...
from ....

$ perl -e 'my %list;
           while(<>){
              chomp; #strip \n from the end
              s/^ *([^ ]*).*/$1/; #keep only 1st word
              $list{$_}++; #increment count
           }
           foreach (keys %list){
               print "$_ $list{$_}\n";
           }' < testfile

come 2
Slovenia 1
I 3
from 2
```